# HTML Onclick doesn't work with negative z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I placed a `negative z-index` property on my image section to prevent it from overlapping the navigation bar, which caused the `hyperlinks` to not function properly. After I fixed that problem, I realized that my left and right buttons for my slideshow would not work. Any help enabling the buttons to work **even with a `negative z-index`**? All the code that I have pasted below is necessary.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1><b>Seattle</b>&Metropolitan</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li>Buildings</li>
                <li id="contact">Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="image-section">
    <img src="img/seattleskyline.jpg" alt="Seattle Skyline" id="center-image" />
    <div id="caption"><div id="caption-text">A panoramic view of 1201 Third Avenue at night</div></div>
    <button id="sliderLeft" onclick="left();"></button>
    <button id="sliderRight" onclick="right();"></button>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="content">
    Seattle's history can be traced back to the 1850s, when pioneers and natives started building a great city filled with a diverse culure, beautiful scenery, and a vibrant enviornment. The metropolitan area of Seattle now is a high-tech hub, in which four Fortune 500 companies reside: <a href="http://www.amazon.com/" alt="Amazon Website"><b>Amazon.com (#49)</b></a>, <a href="http://www.starbucks.com" alt="Starbucks Website"><b>Starbucks (#208)</b></a>, <a href="http://shop.nordstrom.com" alt="Nordstrom Website"><b>Nordstrom (#227)</b></a>, and <a href="http://www.expeditors.com" alt="Expeditors Website"><b>Expeditors International (#428)</b></a>. 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

#container
{
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header h1
{
    font-size: 38px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 100;
}

header nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    float: right;
    z-index: 999;
}

header nav ul li
{
    line-height: 105px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 45px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

header nav ul li a
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#center-image
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
}

#contact
{
    padding-right: 0;
}

.image-section
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

}

.image-section #caption
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #474747;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.image-section button
{
    outline: 0;
}

.image-section #sliderLeft
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    border: 0;
}

.image-section #sliderRight
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    border: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var images = ["img/seattleskyline.jpg", "img/spaceneedle.jpg", "img/ferriswheel.jpg"]
var captions = ["A panoramic view of 1201 Third Avenue at night", "The Seattle's landmark Space Needle", "The Iconic Great Wheel"]
var index = 0;

function left() {
    index -= 2;

    if (index < 0) {
        index = images.length;
    }

    changeImage();
}

function right() {
    changeImage();
}

function changeImage() {
    index++;
    if (index > images.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    var targetImage = document.getElementById("center-image");
    var caption = document.getElementById("caption-text");

    $("#center-image").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        targetImage.src = images[index];
        $("#center-image").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#caption-text").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        caption.innerHTML = captions[index];
        $("#caption-text").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sliderRight").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#sliderLeft").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#caption").fadeIn(1000);
    setInterval(changeImage, 7000);
});
```

Comment: rather than put a negative index on your image section, why not put a large positive index on your navigation bar?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: This is because by doing that you are effectively putting the element under the navigation bar so when you click you're not really clicking the item

Comment: Check that it works for ALL the links, in the fiddle it works for only the first menu item for me I deleted it while I tried to fix that problem. Doe it happen for you too?

Comment: It works all for me. I thought it was perfectly fine.

Comment: Ahhhhh, ok now I see, only the "About" link is actually a link `<a href="about.html">About</a>` ! There was no pointer when hovering over the other two so I thought they were'nt working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `CSS` for  `header nav ul` to :

```
header nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    float: right;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
```

#### [Working jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n0njLru/)

Answer (score 4):

`z-index` take effect when `position` is  `relative` or `absolute` so if you want use it with your `css`

add `position: relative;` as following  so `z-index`s take effect

```
header nav ul
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.image-section
{
    position: relative;
}
.image-section #sliderLeft
{
    z-index: 999;
}

.image-section #sliderRight
    z-index: 999;
}
```

### [**Correct CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqRQRz)